# Not able to migrate the data from Parse to local machine

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

as some of you might aware about the shutting down of parse service in about a  year, i am following the migration process as per their tutorials. However, i am not able to migrate these data from parse to local database(i.e. mongodb).

I've started the mongodb instanse locally on 27017, and also created an admin user as part of migration based on these tutorials. [Reference-1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) & [Reference-2](http://julienrenaux.fr/2016/01/29/complete-parse-server-migration-guide/).

But when i try to migrate the data from parse developer console, i get **No Reachable Servers** or **Network Error** & i don't understand why. I have doubt in the Connection string that i use for this but i am not sure, please find the following image.

[image: parse_Error]

I am new to mongodb so don't have much idea about this, your little help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the migration tool runs at parse.com, the tool needs to be able to access your MongoDB instance over the Internet.

Since you're using a local IP (192.168.1.101), parse.com cannot connect to your IP and the transfer will time out.

Either you need to make your MongoDB reachable from the Internet, or you can - as they do in their guide - use an existing MongoDB service.

Comment: I tried to expose the local port 27017 with ngrok, but the same problem. can i use something like that ?

Comment: @KunalK I'm not familiar with the details of `ngrok`, but the [mongodb migration guide](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App) says _Latency between the Parse hosted database and your self-hosted MongoDB should not exceed 20 ms._ which may be a problem if you tunnel traffic.

Comment: Okay, so currently i should try to host only parse server locally to use it and continue using the existing mongodb service as is ?

Comment: @KunalK I'm sorry but I can only point out the problem and sadly not advice you on the way to go forward, that would depend a lot on your specific situation (for example how much traffic/what's your network speed and latency/how much may it cost/...) as well as personal preference.

Comment: Okay no issues and thanks a lot for your response. :)

Comment: Sorry for late comment but I am able to migrate the data on free mongo lab space(for testing purpose) and what i realize that you need to make the migration space reachable to parse from the internet as Joachim Isaksson said. It won't work in localhost.